# to have somebody down as somebody

Tags: idioms, british-english

Is the idiomatic expression *to have somebody down as somebody* a primarily British phrase?

For example:

- *I never had you down as a Luddite.*

If so, is there a corresponding American idiom?

Comment: I can't address the britishness of the phrase (which is why I'm commenting instead of answering), but a common version of the statement in my neck of the woods (midwestern US) would be "I never figured you for a Luddite."

Comment: I can't really address the Britishness either, but in my area (New York City) *to have someone down* is usually used to mean more literally "to have someone recorded"; for example, "I have you down for 7 PM" = "I have your appointment recorded for 7 PM."

Comment: @Hellion Thank you – this is the phrase I was looking for! You should post an answer. You can address the Britishness by saying something like "I'm an American and the phrase sounds unfamiliar to me".

Comment: @stangdon Thank you. Yeah, the "recorded" meaning is definitely more common. Do you mean that "I never had you down as a ..." sounds weird or unfamiliar to you, like "We need to sit down and sort the problem out"?

Comment: Another idiomatic way of expressing this would be "I never took you for a..."

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+someone+down+as

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/put-down-as

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "to have somebody down as something" is used in the sense of "regard someone as/think someone as.  A synonym of this phrase is "to put someone down as". You use these phrases when you think someone is a particular type or class of person.

However, there are some other verbs or phrases that are more common and idiomatic. For example, you can say:

I never thought of you as a Luddite = I never had/put you down as a Luddite.

Comment: I assume that in this answer, "put someone down as" is being used in the sense of "list someone as" or "put a mark on a form saying someone is".  I assume it is not being used in the sense of "kill someone or something that is in incurable pain". I also assume it is not being used in the sense of "call someone bad names", even though that is the overall purpose of the original example.

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/put-down-as

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20(someone)%20down%20as